# Why useEffect is not constructor function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, toolkit

How useEffect use if I want to have a call or check state before DOM is ready?

In my example, `useEffect` is called after is DOM ready.

E.g I have a parent wrapper, where is my task to check local token, if is token there, redirect user there, it is not, redirect something else.

`App.js` - wrapper

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
...
useEffect(() => {
    if (cookies["_sf-jwt"]) dispatch(setToken(cookies["sf-jwt"])); // this works, state is really updated, but...
}, []);
...
```

When I have to visit a protected route, where is part from state necessary e.g `isUser = false / true`,
first what is mounted in the protected route and her component, not `useEffect` from parent component (App.js above), as a result, I got first on-call old default state, where I can't allow to user to enter on the page, after that, useEffect from app.js works, the state is updated, but it's late, my protected component can't know that?

`Protected.js`

```
...
const user = useSelector(currentUser); // init state from redux
...
render={() => {
 return user.currentUser.loggined ? (  // user.currentUser.loggined is false on init
 children
 ) : (
 <Redirect to="/register"></Redirect>
 );
}}
...
```

My question is, why and how?

I found a solution, escape from `useEffect` put logic on the top of the Component, and now works how I want.

Is my solution safe, and can I do something like this above (escaping from `useEffect` in the future?), is safe for redux?

Comment: The aim of `useEffect()` hook is to perform any synchronization necessary *after the component has been rendered*; the code inside a `useEffect()` hook will always be executed after the component has been rendered.

Comment: @secan, thank you for your answer. Looks logic, I have learned that, but is safe to check all that is necessary to check before the app is ready, on way to put that logic out of any hook?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no particular reason not to have code outside hooks. In a case like the one you described, though, I'd go with a solution like the one posted by Y. Gerbi

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I have learned something new. :)

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is to have an extra state variable in your `App.js` where you check if your user is signed in. Then, only render the router whenever you know you checked the state of the user. This way, the `Protected.js` page for example would always have the correct state of the user.

```
const App = () => {
  const [authChecked, setAuthChecked] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cookies["_sf-jwt"]) {
      dispatch(setToken(cookies["sf-jwt"]))
    }
    setAuthChecked(true)
  }, [])

  return authChecked ? <Router /> : <Loader />
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, looks logical.
But what if the user manually visits ``/protected`` route for example?
He will be available to see what is in that component?

Comment: I think `App.js` should be responsible to handle the routing. So no matter what route you visit, it will always render `App.js` first. And then, in `App.js` the `<Protected />` component is rendered with the correct user state

Comment: @MiloshN. Could you select this as the correct answer if it helped you out? Makes it easier for others who have the same question to find an answer

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned redux, which stores user object. It seems to me that you may use some redux middleware that checks cookies and fill the user state, maybe it's a good idea to fire such action [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) and check cookies there, if they are there - fill user state, otherwise envoke .push() or .redirect() method of your router. Just thinking loudly (: